# this.props.dispatch is not calling reducer

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, store

Hey guys I have a problem with react-redux.
I have a page Login.js. When i click a button the changeSite function is called from which i'm trying to dispatch. I tried a view ways but nothing worked. Would be great if anyone can help me.

Login.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Link } from 'react-router';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

@connect((store) => {
  return {
    user: store.user.state.user,
    registered: store.user.state.registered,
  }
})
export default class Login extends React.Component{

  handlePassword(e){

  }

  handleUsername(e){

  }

  changeSite(){
    this.props.dispatch({type: "CHANGE_REG", payload: !this.props.registered});
    console.log(this.props.registered);
  }

  login(){

  }

  render(){
    console.log(this.props.registered);
    if(this.props.registered === true){
      var loginPage = (
        <div>
          <h2>Login</h2>
          <p>Please login with your credentials</p>
          <form>
            <input placeholder="Username" type="text"/><br/>
            <input placeholder="Password" type="password"/>
            <p>You do not have an account yet?</p>
            <input type="submit" value="register" onClick={this.changeSite.bind(this)}/>
          </form>

        </div>
      );
    }else{
      var loginPage = (
        <div>
          <h2>Register</h2>
          <p>Please register with your credentials</p>
          <form>
            <input placeholder="Username" type="text"/><br/>
            <input placeholder="Password" type="password"/><br/>
            <input placeholder="repeat Password" type="password"/>
            <p>You already have an account?</p>
            <input type="submit" value="login"/>
          </form>

        </div>
      );
    }

    return(
      <div>
        {loginPage}
      </div>
    );
  }


}
```

Reducer:

```
export default function reducer(state={
  user:{
    id: null,
    name: null,
    password: null,
  },
  registered: true,
}, action){
  switch(action.type) {
    case 'USER_LOGIN':{
      return { ...state, user: action.payload}
    }
    case 'CHANGE_REG':{
      return { ...state, registered: action.payload}
    }
  }

  return {state}
}
```

Comment: Did you wrap your Login component in a `Provider` component to expose the store?

Comment: Yes i did actually...

Comment: `console.log(this.props.registered)` is returning some value?

Answer (score 0):

In the place where you define your `store`, you must pass your reducer(s) to the [`createStore`](http://redux.js.org/docs/api/createStore.html#createstorereducer-preloadedstate-enhancer) method.

In the ReduxJS docs you can find [an example with a single store](http://redux.js.org/docs/api/createStore.html#example) and [with multiple stores](http://redux.js.org/docs/api/combineReducers.html#combinereducersreducers) using the `combineReducers` method.

Answer (score 0):

Actually it was a very similar solution:
I had my state returned as an object and not as the state itself.
I changed this:

.
.
return {state};
.
.

with this:

.
.
return state;
.
.

Thanks for your support